# replacing characters in a string in php

Tags: php

I couldn't think of a good question title but my problem is that I have to replace certain characters in a string but don't want to replace characters that are already replaced, for instance,

```
 $s = "abcabacababbccc";
```

if I have to replace `abc` with `bcc` and `bc` with `aa` then I should get

```
 $s = "bccabacababaac";
```

But I'm getting a different string as output because then the other replacing function is called it starts searching string from the start and I ought to avoid it. I have written this code, if anyone could help me sort it out. thanks

```
$_set = "abcacbabccbacab";
    $_set = InvokeRule1($_set);
    $_set = InvokeRule2($_set);
    $_set = InvokeRule3($_set);

function InvokeRule1($set)
{
    $check = false;
        $set = str_replace("abc", "bcc", $set);
        $check = true;

    return $set;
}

 function InvokeRule2($set)
{
    $check = false;
        $set = str_replace("bc", "aa", $set);
        $check = true;
    return $set;
}
```

Comment: im note sure if this idea makes sense, but make sure your doing case sensitive replace, replace lower with upper case, in your 3 rules,  and at the end just change all to lower case.

Comment: Quibble: Your example input string is a different length than your desired output string.

Comment: Use the [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function; but it needs to be done in a single call

Comment: @MarkBaker that's way better than my solution, which involves `preg_replace_callback()` and bears the function name `sin_against_creation()` https://3v4l.org/PBWE5

Comment: `$trans = array("abc" => "bcc", "bc" => "aa");
echo strtr("abcacbabccbacab", $trans);` ? nope, man im getting confused and wasting to much time here :-) some one post a working solution so i can get on with my life please

Comment: @smith Mark did, I did, and your input string is not what OP specified, because that is the correct answer otherwise.

Comment: you should get bccabacababaacc not bccabacababaac

Comment: @Sammitch doh im an idiot, been looking at this to long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well credit to Mark Baker, but no one else seems keen on actually posting an "answer" so:

```
$trans = array("abc" => "bcc", "bc" => "aa");
echo strtr("abcabacababbccc", $trans); //=bccabacababaacc
```

Comment: The result is 'bccabacababaac***c***'. OP accidentally a character in the desired output string.

Comment: 1+ but still the output is  bccabacababaacc with double cc at the end

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
$phrase  = "abcabacababbccc";
$newPhrase = str_replace("abc", "BCC", $phrase);
$newPhrase2 = str_replace("bc", "AA", $newPhrase);
echo strtolower($newPhrase2);
```

Comment: you should try it and then you would see that it wont work

Comment: your code produces "bccacbbcccbacab" the desired output is "bccabacababaac"